# Where am I making mistake in this perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to distinguish, using regular expressions, if readdir is returning file or folder.

This is my code:

```
opendir($dh, $_[0]) || die "Can't open folder!";
while(($filename = readdir($dh))){
   if ($filename =~ /..*\...*/) {...}}
```

Idea of this regex is that it requires at least one character before and after the dot.  I tested this expression (without "/" at the beginning and at end) in perl online regular expression tester and it worked, however in reality condition always return false.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It should work, please, give some filenames that don't match.

Comment: The expression works, but you should write `..*` as `.+`. `+` means “one or more repetitions” in PCRE.

Comment: examples: ".", "..", "abc.xls", "sub1". (sub1 is directory)

Comment: Since when is having _at least one character before and after dot_ a criterion for being a folder or a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your files are following a special convention, you cannot distinguish between files and folders just by looking at the names. You can use `-d` to check whether a path is a folder (see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Alphabetical-Listing-of-Perl-Functions)).

```
my $root = $_[0];
opendir($dh, $root) || die "Can't open folder!";
while(($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    next if $filename =~ /^\.{1,2}$/; # skip . and ..
    if (-d "$root/$filename")
    {
        # $filename is a folder
    }
    else
    {
        # $filename is something else (regular file, symlink, ...)
    }
}
```